# Loop Through a set of Objects

Tags: java, loops, complexity-theory, treemap

I have a map of key-value pairs   of huge size, approximately 10^7, and I have to loop through it 15 times a second in order to update its contents
Is there any class or structure that offers good complexity and reduces the time needed to loop through?

Currently, I am using **TreeMap** but the complexity is **log n** only for contains, put, get and remove. Looping through the elements is of n complexity

Do you know any structure or do you have any idea that may reduce the complexity **below n**?

Comment: How could you possibly loop through n elements in fewer than n steps?

Comment: Are you sure that you have to loop through the entire thing in order to update its contents? What form do the updates take? What sort of data is stored in this structure?

Comment: There does not exist any algorithm that I am familiar with that can reduce the complexity below n.  Here is an algorithm that I am not familiar with that may or may not reduce the complexity below n - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm.  If the algorithm is useful, then perhaps someone (i.e. not me) could implement it.

Comment: not possible to loop thru anything faster then o(n) for obvious reasons, unless you can reduce the number of elements in the collection that needs to be updated

Comment: @emory: That would appear to require a quantum computer.

Comment: It could be that you don't really need to loop through all of the elements - but this will depend on your concrete problem. If you describe it, maybe we can give you some ideas.

Answer (score 5):

If you have to arbitrary loop over the entire collection, you will not get better than n.  If you have to loop the entire collection, you could use a simple ArrayList.  but if you need to access specific data in the collection using a key, TreeMap will be fine.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. How on earth are you going to look at n items in less than n time? I suppose a hypothetical parallel machine with an arbitrary number of cores could do this in linear time, by simply examining all n elements in parallel. The problem is still O(n) for parallel algorithms using a fixed (finite) number of processors, but certainly you could speed it up via parallelism.

Comment: This is a very good practical answer, but I suspect you could iterate thru the entire collection below n using a quantum computer.  However, until java is implemented on quantum computers, this is a moot point.

Answer (score 0):

You can't beat the O(n) bound on any sequential (or finitely parallel) computer, if your problem is just to look at all of O(n) values.

If you have a finitely parallel machine and depending on exactly how you're updating the elements, you could achieve speedup. For instance, using CUDA and a GPU or OpenMP/MPI and a cluster/multi-core workstation, you could compute A[i] = A[i]^3 or some such with good speedup. Of course, then there's the question of communication... but this might be something to look at.

Comment: I know that the time needed to loop through a set of object is proportional to the size of the set but I asked whether someone knows any structure that might improve at least a bit the looping time.

I have a 2D Double array 24X500000 and this array is updated 15 times each second (each cell is geometrically decreased by a coefficient). Most of the cells are 0; hence updating them (multiplying by a coefficient won't have any effect except than increasing computational time).

Comment: Instead of having this huge 2D array I thought to have a TreeMap and keep only the nonzero values with row+Column as the key and the cell's value as the node's value.

My question is: Does a TreeMap<String,Double> require more computations instead of an ArrayList<String[]>.
Is there any other structure that performs better?